# Generate objects with dynamic "key" using spread operators

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I want to generate an object where the key is the value of the index from the mapped data as shown in the code below

```
{data.map(({ quest, answers }, index) => {
                  <Radio.Group
                    name={index}
                    defaultValue={def}
                    onChange={(value) => {
                    setVal({...(val), index: JSON.stringify(value)}  )
                      
                    }}
                  >
                    {answers.map((ans, key) => {
                      return (
                        <Radio value={key + 1}>
                          {ans}
                        </Radio>
                      );
                    })}
                  </Radio.Group>
})}
```

So "index" in this line

`setVal({...(val), index: JSON.stringify(value)}  )`

should be from this line

`{data.map(({ quest, answers }, index) => {`

The problem is the code above returns the index value as the string "index" instead of the value of index from the mapped data i am working with

Comment: Well makes sense, maybe show us how the value object looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this:-

`setVal({...(val), [index]: JSON.stringify(value)}` )